# CSS issues with NavBar

Tags: css, html

I am having a couple issues with my Navigation bar. The first issue is I cannot figure out how to make the "active" size the same size as my hover. You will notice that the entire height of the navigation bar is highlighted on active.

Secondly, for some reason it isn't as apparent on codepen but in my actual situation my "main" div is on the same plane as the navbar resulting in the drop shadow to not be even and crisp. Hopefully you can see what I mean from the following image. I have tried playing with z-index with no luck.

https://codepen.io/kjpolker/pen/RMqNbL

[image: example]

Image is of the navigation bar itnersecting with the main div. The shadow almost "fades" out on the edge, how can I put the shadow in front?

**HTML**

```
<body>
<nav class="navigation-bar">
<a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="100" height="100"/></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">TAB 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TAB 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TAB 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TAB 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TAB 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main class="main">
    <article class="summary">
        <p></p>
    </article>
    <article id="image">
        <img src="images/map.png" alt="" width="80%" height="80%" />
    </article>
</main>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {text-align: center;}

body {
    background-image: url(../images/BG.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%; background-position: top left; background-repeat: repeat;
    justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment / centering */
    align-items: flex-start; /* prevents the #menu to fill the remaining height of the body */
}

.navigation-bar {
    opacity: .9;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #2A2A2A;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    /*
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    */
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* used with 100% wrapper */
ul  {
    display: inline;
    display: flex; /* displays children inline */
    width: 60%;
    height: 120px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #2A2A2A;
}

li {
    flex: 1; /* each takes as much width as it can, i.e. 25% */
}

li:last-child {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}

li a {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font: Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #EAEAEA;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 0; /* This adjusts the height of the tabs */
}

li a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(#404040, #3E3E3E);
}

.active {
    background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
}

p {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Used in Home */
.main {
    opacity: .75;
    color: #EAE0D2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, For your first issue changing

`.active {
    background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
}`

to

`.active a{
    background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
}`

will solve the issue.

Comment: unbelievable how something so small can make a difference, in this case. the lowercase letter a... Thank you. Still seeking the second part.

Comment: The second part is not so evident in codepen, my wild guess is it's something related to browser compatibility.. if you can tell more, i can try out something.

Comment: It is odd, I have added my entire code to codepen and it didn't change the results.

Comment: After looking at it further on my screen I can definitely conclude the issue is that the shadow is in fact behind the "main" div. Because "main"
 is set to a .75 opacity you can still make it out, but it is not as dark.

Comment: I guess it is something related to z-index and z-index will work with only relatively positioned elements.. please check your code.

Comment: I was able to solve it by adding `position: relative;` to the div. Apparently z-index will not effect a static position.

`z-index: 1; position: relative;`